# Increment quantity or ImportRow in DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 datagridviews in c#. Lets call them dgv1 and dgv2. dgv1 is bound to DataTable dt1 which is populated from SQL server. dgv2 is bound to DataTable dt2. dt2 is populated by copying rows from dt1 on Enter.

In dt2 I have one additional column 'QUantity' which should be increased when user wants to add row which already exists.

Code to copy row from dt1 to dt2:

```
 DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgv1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
 DataRow dr = currentDataRowView.Row;

 dt2.ImportRow(dr);
 dgv2.DataSource = dtInvoiceItems;
```

How to check if row already exists in dt2 based one column which is primary and increase quantity if it does exist or importrow if it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find row by the primary key: `DataRow row = dt2.Rows.Find(primary_key_value);` where `primary_key_value` can be obtained by `dr[dt2.PrimaryKey[0]]`.
To increase quantity: `row["QUantity"] = (int)row["QUantity"] + 1;`.
The resulting code:

```
DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgv1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
DataRow dr = currentDataRowView.Row;

DataRow row = dt2.Rows.Find(dr[dt2.PrimaryKey[0].ColumnName]);
if (row == null)
    dt2.ImportRow(dr);
else
    row["QUantity"] = (int)row["QUantity"] + 1;
```

**EDIT** Error fixed

Comment: I don't quite understand this part "dr[dt2.PrimaryKey[0]]", and I get error: "Additional information: Column 'primary_key_column_name' does not belong to table." I am missing something.

Comment: The expression `dr[dt2.PrimaryKey[0]]` has the following meaning - get value from the row `dr` and a column with the name of the `dt2` primary. I've updated the sample to fix that error.